# Automatically replace names in data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame in R, called `arcs`, that has some values of which I would like to change the name.

I would like to change the name based on another data frame, called `data2`.

`data2` has two columns, the first column is the old name, and the second column is the new name.

I would like to go through `arcs` and if there is a name in `arcs` that appears in the first column of `data2`, I would like to change it to the second column of `data2`.

Is that possible?

For example, if this was arcs

```
data 1    blah 1
blah 2    data 2
blah 3    data 3
blah 4    blah 5
data 4    data 5
```

and this was data2

```
data 1    real 1
data 2    real 2
data 3    real 3
data 4    real 4
data 5    real 5
```

I would want the new arcs to look like this:

```
real 1    blah 1
blah 2    real 2
blah 3    real 3
blah 4    blah 5
real 4    real 5
```

Comment: This doesn't sound that difficult, but can you provide some *simple* example data that represents your problem. A handful of (even made up) cases in `arcs` or `names` would do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Can you please clarify if you have a `data.frame` or a `matrix` for your data? The results of `is.data.frame(arcs)` and `is.matrix(arcs)` will tell you, and will allow answers to be clarified.

Comment: If you have a dataframe, then you probably also have these as factors. Unless you clarify with str(dfrms) or show how to build an example, you are just wasting people's time.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your data are both `matrix` structures rather than `data.frames` (going on your comments), then try this:

```
arcs <- matrix(c("data1","blah2","blah3","blah4","data4",
                 "blah1","data2","data3","blah5","data5"),ncol=2)
data2 <- matrix(c("data1","data2","data3","data4","data5",
                 "real1","real2","real3","real4","real5"),ncol=2)

> arcs
#     [,1]    [,2]   
#[1,] "data1" "blah1"
#[2,] "blah2" "data2"
#[3,] "blah3" "data3"
#[4,] "blah4" "blah5"
#[5,] "data4" "data5"
> data2
#     [,1]    [,2]   
#[1,] "data1" "real1"
#[2,] "data2" "real2"
#[3,] "data3" "real3"
#[4,] "data4" "real4"
#[5,] "data5" "real5"
```

Fix it up:

```
matches <- match(arcs,data2[,1])
arcs[!is.na(matches)] <- data2[,2][matches[!is.na(matches)]]
```

Result:

```
> arcs
#     [,1]    [,2]   
#[1,] "real1" "blah1"
#[2,] "blah2" "real2"
#[3,] "blah3" "real3"
#[4,] "blah4" "blah5"
#[5,] "real4" "real5"
```

Comment: I got the error `Error in arcs$vals : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

Comment: It sounds like you have a `matrix` not a `data.frame`. This is why providing clear examples is important. Can you post `dput(head(arcs))` and `dput(head(data2))` in your original question?

Comment: @user2651613 - Updated to hopefully address your issue.

Comment: +1 ..even it looks odd to have a matrix containing "data" and "real"(multi types)!

Answer (score 2):

The answer of thelatemail is good but works only with matrix. Here a solution that works with data.frames ie with multi types columns. I am using `%in%` (similar to `match`) and looping through all the columns of  arcs.

```
do.call(cbind,lapply(arcs,function(x){
       x[x %in% data2$V1] <- 
         data2$V2[x %in% data2$V1]
       x
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arcs<-structure(list(col1 = structure(c(4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("blah 2", 
"blah 3", "blah 4", "data 1", "data 4"), class = "factor"), col2 = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 5L), .Label = c("blah 1", "blah 5", "data 2", "data 3", 
"data 5"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("col1", "col2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

> arcs
    col1   col2
1 data 1 blah 1
2 blah 2 data 2
3 blah 3 data 3
4 blah 4 blah 5
5 data 4 data 5

data2<-structure(list(oldname = structure(1:5, .Label = c("data 1", 
"data 2", "data 3", "data 4", "data 5"), class = "factor"), newname = structure(1:5, .Label = c("real 1", 
"real 2", "real 3", "real 4", "real 5"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("oldname", 
"newname"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

 > data2
  oldname newname
1  data 1  real 1
2  data 2  real 2
3  data 3  real 3
4  data 4  real 4
5  data 5  real 5

arcs$col1<-ifelse(as.character(arcs$col1)==as.character(data2$oldname),as.character(data2$newname),as.character(arcs$col1))
> arcs$col1
[1] "real 1" "blah 2" "blah 3" "blah 4" "data 4"

arcs$col2<-ifelse(as.character(arcs$col2)==as.character(data2$oldname),as.character(data2$newname),as.character(arcs$col2))
> arcs$col2
[1] "blah 1" "real 2" "real 3" "blah 5" "real 5"

>arcs
    col1   col2
1 real 1 blah 1
2 blah 2 real 2
3 blah 3 real 3
4 blah 4 blah 5
5 data 4 real 5
```

Comment: I don't think it did anything